# Razorpay:BAD_REQUEST_ERROR Please provide your api key for authentication purposes

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, payment-gateway, razorpay

I am newbie, working on codeigniter and I am using the razorpay payment gateway apis for transferring the amount using route concept as defined in the razorpay documentation. When I am calling the api using `curl` I am getting the error:

> {
> "error": {
> "code": "BAD_REQUEST_ERROR",
> "description": "Please provide your api key for authentication purposes.",
> "source": null,
> "step": null,
> "reason": null,
> "metadata": {}
> }
> }

the code i used is :

```
$url = 'https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/pay_E8JR8E0XyjUSZd/transfers';

/* Array Parameter Data */
$data = ['account' => 'va_FWSvFCwsaV1w5K', 'amount' => 90, 'currency' => 'INR'];

/* pass encoded JSON string to the POST fields */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        
/* set the content type json */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json','YOUR_KEY_ID','YOUR_KEY_SECRET'));
        
/* set return type json */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        
/* execute request */
$result = curl_exec($ch);
         
/* close cURL resource */
curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);
```

How should I place my key and secret in curl so that error does not occur.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/59005454/4703530

Comment: refer - https://razorpay.com/docs/api/orders/#create-an-order

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory. This line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json','YOUR_KEY_ID','YOUR_KEY_SECRET'));
```

Should contain your actual key and secret, not `your_key_id` and `your_key_secret` placeholder strings. Otherwise, authorization will fail

Comment: i have used actual key and secret but error remains same @Javier Larroulet

Answer (score 0):

You will require to encode key:secret in base64 format. And then add another header Authorization to make this API working.

```
headers = {
   "Content-Type": "application/json",
   "Authorization": "Basic " + encode_base64(Key:Secret)
}
```

In your case,

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization:Basic (encoded_string)'));
```

Let me know if it works for you!